# Eclipse TODOs not showing up in tasks view

Tags: eclipse, lua

I know there are about a million questions on this topic, I have read them and they have been unhelpful so far. I am very new to eclipse so forgive me if I get things a bit wrong.

I have an eclipse project with some Lua files. I am using Luaeclipse to provide a Lua perspective and syntax highlighting.

I simply want to be able to do this:

-- TODO Implement this thing

And have it show up in the Tasks view. I know this is possible, but it just won't work for me.

Under Project > Properties, I have gone in to Lua settings and set the "Enable searching for Task Tags" checkbox, and I have double checked the the tags I am searching for are correct.

I don't know what else to do, this should be easy.

**Edit**
Here is what my workspace looks like, with the relevant settings shown.
[image: Here is what my workspace looks like, with the relevant settings shown.]

Comment: It may require you rebuild your Lua project.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my project wasn't in the build path... Adding it fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Adding task tag in Lua editor didn't trigger adding task into "**Tasks**" view. I think it may be a bug of the eclipse plugin in Luaeclipse.

Declare that, i haven't used Luaeclipse. So, maybe you should check whether it support tasks tag in Lua editor firstly. The way to check follows:
You can open menu "**Window**" -> "**Preferences**", then filter by text "**Task Tags**".

If there is no "**Task Tags**" under "Lua"(Or something else), maybe you can't use tasks tag in Lua editor.

If there is, maybe you can try to trigger adding task manually.

1. You can set "**Case sensitive task tag names**" to be checked and "**Apply**". Then there will be a dialog to let you decide whether rebuild project to scan task tag, and select "**No**" (we don't want to change it really, just let its state change.)
2. Select "**Restore Defaults**" and "**Apply**", the dialog would pop up again. In this time, you can select "**Yes**" to let it scan tasks tag in your project to trigger adding tasks into "**Tasks**" view.

Hope what I supposed works.

---

**Edit**: Maybe, you can try LDT(Lua Development Tools), it works well. 
[image]

Comment: Luaeclipse definitely supports task tags. Doing what you suggested brings up "Task tags" under Lua. Doing what you suggested brings up a dialogue asking if I want to rebuild - so I select yes but still nothing comes up in the task view.

Comment: hmmm, which version of your Luaeclipse? I can download it and have a try.

Comment: Eclipse version: 3.7.2
LuaEclipse version: 1.1

Comment: Hi Cameron, I tried to install Luaeclipse1.1 via updatesite: http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/update-site/site.xml, given in [http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/manual.html#installation](http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/manual.html#installation). But always failed. I downloaded the Luaeclipse plugin and installed it manually, but there is few things in "Preference -> Lua". So, I couldn't verify it. But, there is another good news. I installed "Lua Development Tools" searched in "Help -> Eclipse Marketplace". The task view works fine. Maybe, you can try "Lua Development Tools".

Comment: Lua Development Tools has the same issue... Which makes me think this is not an eclipse issue... What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to "touch" or "tickle" the lua file in question: Make any little edit (add and remove a space) then save it. If your scenario matches mine, the TODOs will magically appear.